# Android: problema con OnClick en Floating-ArcMenu

Tags: android, onclick

Estoy haciendo una app con Android Studio y utilizo un componente llamado Floating-ArcMenu (https://github.com/BrotherV/Floating-ArcMenu) que va de maravilla. El problema es el siguiente:
Cuando pulso el botón se abre el menú y al pulsar un ítem por primera vez, el menú se cierra. Vuelvo a pulsar el botón, se abre el menú y ahora sí, al pulsar el ítem se ejecuta el OnClick correspondiente. Eso pasa con todos los ítems del menú. Funcionan bien a partir de la segunda pulsación, nunca en la primera.

Incluyo captura del menú desplegado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluyo código de la creación del menú y de sus ítems:

```
val itemsIconos = intArrayOf(R.drawable.color, R.drawable.align, R.drawable.formato, R.drawable.posicion, R.drawable.escala)
    val itemsTexto = arrayOf("Color", "Alineación", "Formato", "Posición", "Escala")

    arcMenu.showTooltip(true)
    arcMenu.setToolTipBackColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primaryLightColor))
    arcMenu.setToolTipCorner(6f)
    arcMenu.setToolTipPadding(2f)
    arcMenu.setToolTipTextSize(16)
    arcMenu.setToolTipTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primaryTextColor))
    arcMenu.setAnim(300, 300, ArcMenu.ANIM_MIDDLE_TO_RIGHT, ArcMenu.ANIM_MIDDLE_TO_RIGHT, ArcMenu.ANIM_INTERPOLATOR_ACCELERATE_DECLERATE, ArcMenu.ANIM_INTERPOLATOR_ACCELERATE_DECLERATE)

    val itemCount = itemsIconos.size
    for (i in 0 until itemCount) {
        val item = FloatingActionButton(this)
        item.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI)
        item.setIcon(itemsIconos[i])
        item.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primaryDarkColor))
        arcMenu.setChildSize(item.intrinsicHeight)

        arcMenu.addItem(item, itemsTexto[i], {
            //añadir funciones listener a los botones
            when (i) {
                0 -> it.setOnClickListener {
                    fl_ac_mo.contentRes = R.layout.mn_flo_color
                    fl_ac_mo.open()
                }
                1 -> it.setOnClickListener {
                    fl_ac_mo.contentRes = R.layout.mn_flo_align
                    fl_ac_mo.open()
                }
                2 -> it.setOnClickListener {
                    fl_ac_mo.contentRes = R.layout.mn_flo_formato
                    fl_ac_mo.open()
                }
                3 -> it.setOnClickListener {
                    fl_ac_mo.contentRes = R.layout.mn_flo_posicion
                    fl_ac_mo.open()
                }
                4 -> it.setOnClickListener {
                    fl_ac_mo.contentRes = R.layout.mn_flo_escala
                    fl_ac_mo.open()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

¿Cómo resuelvo para que el OnClick de los ítems funcionen desde la primera apertura?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué dice el `LogCat` o la consola de errores?

Comment: Como es un problema relacionado con una vista personalizada, te recomiendo que también busques una solución en las issues del proyecto https://github.com/BrotherV/Floating-ArcMenu/issues.

Comment: Ok, gracias, voy a ello.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado.

Un listener dentro de un listener no es una buena idea.

Aquí la solución:

```
arcMenu.addItem(item, itemsTexto[i], View.OnClickListener() {
            //añadir funciones listener a los botones
            when (i) {
                0 -> fl_ac_mo.contentRes = R.layout.mn_flo_color
                1 -> fl_ac_mo.contentRes = R.layout.mn_flo_align
                2 -> fl_ac_mo.contentRes = R.layout.mn_flo_formato
                3 -> fl_ac_mo.contentRes = R.layout.mn_flo_posicion
                4 -> fl_ac_mo.contentRes = R.layout.mn_flo_escala
            }
            fl_ac_mo.open()
        })
```